# postfix localhost mail server

Tags: postfix-mta, mail-server

I have system log

```
Jul 28 20:37:44 pi postfix/pickup[853]: 3F4F1A2C0: uid=0 from=<root>
Jul 28 20:37:44 pi postfix/cleanup[863]: 3F4F1A2C0: message-id=<20150728183744.3F4F1A2C0@mail.domain.tld>
Jul 28 20:37:44 pi postfix/qmgr[854]: 3F4F1A2C0: from=<root@domain.tld>, size=413, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 28 20:37:44 pi postfix/local[865]: 3F4F1A2C0: to=<root@domain.tld>, relay=local, delay=0.26, delays=0.24/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul 28 20:37:44 pi postfix/qmgr[854]: 3F4F1A2C0: removed
```

But mail doesnt come to mailBox or mailDir

command mail does not show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured Maildir
and command mail can read only mailbox.. so I must to install mutt or something else...